# Can Syed \ Hashmi receive Zakat?

Tags: zakat, ahl-ul-bayt

Can someone who is from a Syed or Hashmi family  (for example from among ahl-al-Bayt the off-spring of our beloved prophet and his family) receive money from Zakat?

Please give proof.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 2):

Banu Hashim are excluded from receiving Zakat based on:

- > ... Verily these sadaqat are the impurities of people, and they are not permissible for Muhammad (may peace be upon him), and for the family of Muhammad. ... (See for example in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/12/219))
- > Leave it, leave it, throw it; don't you know that we do not eat the sadaqa? ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/12/210))

This ruling applies whether or not they have been given the Khums or not. Note that even the clients of banu Hashim are/were included in this:

> Abu Rafi (RAA) narrated that The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) appointed a man from Bani Makhzum to collect the Zakah. The man said to Abu Rafi', ‘Accompany me so that you may get a share of it.' Abu Rafi, replied, ‘No! Not until I go to the Prophet and ask him’ He went to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and asked him, and the Prophet replied, “The client (slave) of a certain tribe are like (the members of the tribe) themselves and Zakah is not lawful for us.” Related by Ahmad, the three Imams, Ibn Khuzaimah and Ibn Hibban. ([Bulugh al-Maraam](https://sunnah.com/urn/2107830))

As for banu Al-Muttalib there are two opinions, one saying that they are excluded from this rule as they are not from the family of Muhammad () as stated in the first hadith above. Another is based on the fact that they also receive the Khums based on:

> I and 'Uthman bin 'Affan went to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! You have given to Bani Al-Muttalib and left us although they and we are of the same kinship to you." Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Bani Muttalib and Bani Hashim are one and the same." The Prophet (ﷺ) did not give a share to Bani `Abd Shams and Bani Naufai.
>
> (Ibn 'Is-haq said, "Abd Shams and Hashim and Al-Muttalib were maternal brothers and their mother was 'Atika bint Murra and Naufal was their paternal brother.) ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/57/48))

Answer (score 1):

Entire Banu Hashim can not receive Zakat, not just direct descendants of Prophet (SAW).

Answer (score 0):

In Islam scale of Zakat receiver is not specified for any family. Everyone including person belongs to Syed family can be given Zakat if he falls in the criteria of people deserving Zakat which is clearly defined in Islam. 
However, SADQA is prohibited for persons belongs to Syed Family bcos they belongs to great Family of Holy Prophet PBUH. ..

Answer (score 0):

No any type of syed can take zakat from non syed. Because syed belong with our beloved prophet Muhammad (SAW) family . So they are respected and can't take zakat . But syed can take zakat from another syed because they have equally rights. You can search about sadat respect.

Comment: Consider adding evidences that support your claims! (See [answer]).

Answer (score 0):

syeds can not take zakat from non syed they can only take zakat from antother syed but the question arises in every ones mind tht what should a syed do if he or she is poor then in this situation non syed have right to give khumas from NON SYED earnigs so to have barkat in their own earnings in this way we can help syed and indirectly we can also help us because syed family is so respectable(family of our beloved prophet(S.A.W.W)

Answer (score -1):

no it is not allowed in islam that syeds will take zakat because syeds come from prophet family which is so respectable only one case syed can take zakat that on syed give to other syed